# SQL Server Login auditing capturing Logon events when set to Failed logins only

Tags: sql-server, logins, logs

I have an issue where within my SQL Server 2016 Standard instance, `Login auditing` is set to `Failed logins only` but within the `ERRORLOG` file, it is capturing `Both failed and succesful logins`. Once I observed the behavior, I thought that the reason for this was that I had an `ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON` trigger enabled.

This trigger was created to prevent usage of a SQL Server credential when connecting with SQL Server Management Studio that originates from a `host_name` that has not been delegated access. This was added to allow access from specific terminals outside of the domain (but within the same network) that the SQL Server is hosted on.

This is the trigger:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER SSMSRemoteBlock
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT
                *
            FROM
                sys.dm_exec_sessions es
            WHERE
                es.login_name = 'ExternalDBA'
                AND es.host_name NOT IN ('ExternalHost1', 'ExternalHost2')
                AND es.program_name LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%')
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

However, even after dropping the trigger, restarting MSSQLSERVER, and even the entire server, `Logon` events are still being captured. I dug even deeper and I browsed to `Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer` within the registry, and the `AuditLevel` `REG_DWORD` was not explicitly specified. So, I manually added it with a value of `2` for `Failed logins only`. Restarted MSSQLSERVER again to no avail. Set the value to `0` for `None` and restarted... still capturing all login events.

What else could contribute to this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like you have C2 or common criteria turned on.

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft C2 is disabled, and common criteria isn't available in Standard Edition. So unfortunately I'm still at a dead end.

Comment: Can you please run this and post your output? `SELECT 
    S.name AS 'Audit Name', 
    S.is_state_enabled,     
    S.type_desc AS 'Write Location',
     SA.name,
   SA.is_state_enabled,     
   SAD.audit_action_name,
  SAD.audited_result
FROM sys.server_audit_specification_details AS SAD
  JOIN sys.server_audit_specifications AS SA
    ON SAD.server_specification_id = SA.server_specification_id
  JOIN sys.server_audits AS S
    ON SA.audit_guid = S.audit_guid`

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Apologies for the late reply. I ran the above and received no results from the query.